# In the component callback function inside how to access the current component of the property, in angular 2?

Tags: angular, components

I have two components: **listComponent.ts** and **changeStatusComponent.ts**, which are associated with the list page **listComponent.html** and the state modifier page **changeStatusComponent.html**, the **listComponent.html** page has a table in which each row has a modified status button that pops up **ChangeStatusComponent.html** page when the button is clicked , modify the status and save it later, the **listComponent.html** page is modified by the automatic update (**Instead of refreshing the page**)

**Questions**: Please refer to the comments section

listComponent.ts

```
changeLevel(item: any){
    let res = this.dialog.open(ChangeLevelComponent);
    res.componentInstance.userId = item.userId;
    res.componentInstance.cb = function(item: any){
        //item is Modified object({userId:xxx, level: xxx}).

        /*
        I want to find the corresponding record by item.id 
        and then modify the level attribute of the record.

        But here I can not access the xxx component properties 
        (datas - user binding listComponent.html page table target)
        */

        //changeLevel method inside this can only access the properties 
        //of the ChangeLevelComponent component 

        /*
        Here's how to access the listComponent component's properties, 
        which are used to bind to the xxx.html table
            */

    };
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the answer.

```
changeLevel(item: any){
    var self = this;
    let res = this.dialog.open(ChangeLevelComponent);
    res.componentInstance.ffClassId = item.ffClassId;
    res.componentInstance.cb = (item: any) => {

        console.log(self.listService.list);


    };

}
```

Comment: If you are using the arrow syntax, you don't need the `var self = this` trick.

Comment: @echonax Ok, Thank you for your reply !